# Como fazer uma div ocupar a página inteira?

Tags: html, css

Quero criar um menu lateral e o formato dele vai ser `widht: 250px` e `height: 100%` encostado no canto esquerdo do navegador, porém ao colocar essas qualidades no css, a div não fica com 100%, fica apenas do tamanho da `<ul>` e com um espaçamento superior e lateral-esquerdo.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Já definiu as alturas dos elementos `html` e `body` também?

Comment: Ainda não Anderson, estou aprendendo agora html e css e esse é meu primeiro projeto sozinho que estou criando. Por enquanto está assim: `.longBar
 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(66, 79, 90);
 }`

Comment: Definir a altura do elemento como `100%` faz com que ele se ajuste à altura de seu elemento pai. Se este não ocupar a tela inteira também, não funcionará como esperado. Defina as alturas de `html` e `body` como `100%` também e terá algum resultado. Algo como `html, body { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: Bem dito Anderson!. Defini `body { height: 100%; postion: absolute }` e minha div longBar coloquei `height: 100%; position: relative`. Funcionou! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Quando você defini altura em porcentagem ele se baseia nos elementos pai, ou seja, `html` e `body` como o Anderson falou nos comentários. veja um exemplo:

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
    
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Observe que agora o `body` tem altura 100%. Agora todos filhos de `body` podem ter altura 100% inclusive o `.menu` defini cores pra ficar mais compreensível, nunca se esqueça que os elementos filhos se baseiam no elemento pai.

Referente a posições absolutas e relativa não é necessário para este exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!
Creio eu que a melhor forma de alcançar o que você deseja com altura ocupando a tela inteira é definir a altura da sua div em "vh" = Viewport Height, traduzindo: Altura da sua Janela.

Dê esse valor pra sua div para ter a altura completa da sua janela:

```
.longBar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh; /* Note a medida */
    background-color: rgb(66, 79, 90);
}
```

A vantagem desse método é não depender de medidas previamente definidas para o `body` nem pro `html`.